# he has scored or he scored

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

My non-native English speaking friends and I meet regularly and learn English from one another. At our last meeting, I talked about an amateur hockey player, who is my friend. This is what I said to them.

**(ex) To win a special trophy, a player in the local hockey league needs to score at least seventy goals in a season. Over the last five seasons, John scored sixty five or fewer goals per season and marginally missed the mark for a trophy. During the first half of the current season, he managed to score fifty goals. Two months into the second half, he, however, succeeded in scoring the seventh goal to qualify for the trophy. He is expecting to reach an eighty goal mark at the end of the season.**

Most of my non-native English speaking friends found a few mistakes. They said that you have to use the present perfect to relate to the phrase "Over the last five seasons". In addition, you have to use the definite article "the trophy" because at the beginning of my first sentence, I have already mentioned "a special trophy". So, the definite article is required to reference it again. Lastly, they said it's wrong to use multiple tenses in my paragraph.

Are the tenses I am using really wrong?

Comment: There are lots of questions on past and present perfect tense here.  Do any of them help?  Why, or why not?

Comment: The responses to the previous related questions don't seem to help because I don't know how to relate other people's comments to my own scenario. I am really lost. None of my friends are native English speakers. I can't figure out who's correct.

Comment: There is nothing in that passage that seems unusual to me. (I might change *expecting* to *expected*; that's the only thing that interrupts the flow—but that's stylistic; it's not actually ungrammatical as it is.) Without a *specific* issue, I'd say you have nothing to worry about.